# Mailchimp: How to Capture the Update Profile Form submitting date

Tags: forms, mailchimp

## Background

Using Mailchimp, I'm building a campaign to collect subscriber's preferences update.
It's important for me to know the **date** that a subscriber *submitted* an `Update profile form`.

I'm currently using the free plan but expected to upgrade to the monthly paid plan (what they call Growing Business).

## The problem

I was not able to capture the date of submission.

## What I have tried

You can easily get the date of the last update.
But, this field can be affected by other events on the subscriber.

## My question

How can I save the date that the subscriber submitted the `update profile form`? (not the date of the last update of the subscriber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a response I received from an official representative of MailChimp,
on **May 10, 2018**:

> "While this is currently not a feature I see how this option could be useful for you, and I would be more than happy to submit that as feedback to our development team".